# GetAllNetworkInterfaces and Performance Counter, both showing different sets of interfaces

Tags: c#, performancecounter, network-interface

I would like to get all the network interface instances which are up/enabled.

While trying to fetch all instance for Network Interface, both  "NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()" and "PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface")" giving different results set.

What could be the reason?

```
foreach(var nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    Console.WriteLine(nic.Description.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(nic.OperationalStatus.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine("============");

var category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
foreach (var ntwrkInterfaceName in category.GetInstanceNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ntwrkInterfaceName);
}
```

Here is sample output,

**Output From NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()**
1.Some Driver (Up)
2. Loopback Interface 1 (Up)

**Output From PerformanceCounterCategory(Network Interface)**
1. Intel[R]  Network Connection#
2. Intel[R]  Network Connection

Comment: Could you add a sample output?

Comment: I added the output

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your machine, your code on my machine yields the same results for both statements, the performance counter skips the loopback interface though